# How to draw charts/graphs in Flex 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, graph, charts, flex3

I am using flex builder 3 with SDK 3.5. I make a AIR application and I want to Draw some graphs on it. I search the internet and the examples did not work. Am I missing something or I have to install some chart relating packages? I am new to Flex.

Comment: If you use the adobe flex builder standard edition you may not have the charting package inside the sdk. Only professional version allows you to use charts

Comment: can I add charting package in flex standard edition?

Comment: The charting controls are a feature of Adobe Flex® Builder™ Professional. You can create charts in your Flex applications with Flex Builder Standard, but the charting controls will have a watermark on them. Please read the help page http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part1_charting_1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [Bindable]
 public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    {Month:"Jan", Profit:2000, Expenses:1500},
    {Month:"Feb", Profit:1000, Expenses:200},
    {Month:"Mar", Profit:1500, Expenses:500}
 ]);

 public var myChart:BarChart;
 public var series1:BarSeries;
 public var series2:BarSeries;
 public var legend1:Legend;

 public function init():void {
    // Create the chart object and set some 
    // basic properties.
    myChart = new BarChart();
    myChart.showDataTips = true;
    myChart.dataProvider = expenses;

    // Define the category axis.
    var vAxis:CategoryAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    vAxis.categoryField = "Month" ;
    vAxis.dataProvider =  expenses;
    myChart.verticalAxis = vAxis;

    // Add the series.
    var mySeries:Array=new Array();
    series1 = new BarSeries();
    series1.xField="Profit";
    series1.yField="Month";
    series1.displayName = "Profit";
    mySeries.push(series1);

    series2 = new BarSeries();
    series2.xField="Expenses";
    series2.yField="Month";
    series2.displayName = "Expenses";
    mySeries.push(series2);

    myChart.series = mySeries;

    // Create a legend.
    legend1 = new Legend();
    legend1.dataProvider = myChart;

    // Attach chart and legend to the display list.
    p1.addChild(myChart);
    p1.addChild(legend1);
 }   
 ]]></mx:Script>
  <mx:Panel id="p1" title="Bar Chart Created in ActionScript"/>
 </mx:Application>
```

go [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_intro_7.html) for more information.